# Content-Length, Flask, Python, заголовок для передачи картинки

Tags: python, веб-программирование, http, flask

В общем, пытался создать картинку, и затем ее вывести, вроде бы должно было работать, но когда задаю Content-Length оно не работает, не знаю в чем беда, прошу помощи, пробовал уже и st_size из os, и len() файла, не работает

```
def img():
# img()
with open('img.png', 'rb') as f:
    timee = time.time()
    now = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timee)
    normal_time = time.localtime(time.mktime(now.timetuple()))
    string = f.read()
    stat_info = os.stat('img.png')
    req = make_response('img.png')
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
    req.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="img.png"'
    req.headers['Content-Length'] = stat_info.st_size # тут размер Content-Lenght
    req.headers['Expires'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'
    req.headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
    req.headers['Last-Modified'] = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', normal_time)
    req.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
    req.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'post-check=0,pre-check=0'
    req.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0'
    req.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    print(stat_info.st_size)
    print(len(string))
    print(Response())
    return req
```

По итогу такая ошибка:

[image: et::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH]

Если упустить Content-Lenght, то ничего не выводится, черный квадрат с белыми рамками

Comment: Если вы хотите вывести картинку — значит в `make_response` нужно поместить именно байты картинки; вы же вместо этого поместили туда строку `img.png` длина которой 7 байт в кодировке utf-8, значит `Content-Length` должен быть тоже `7`

Comment: Посмотрите, у меня есть пример по генерации qr-code, там есть возврат и скачивание картинок: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a79651565b1f8506068ae99b18c31c2bea69077f/flask__webservers/generate_qrcode/main.py